# Hash table approach to efficient sparse tensor for host and device in CUDA

Tags: c++11, cuda, hashtable, gpgpu, scientific-computing

I want to implement efficient code to work with multidimensional sparse tensors that will be used to store values generated by recursions either on the CPU or the GPU. To achieve this goal, my guess  is that a hash table with [aligned storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) of data offers a good compromise between storage and performance.

Now I have a minimal version of the implementation for the CPU, code is below.

My aim is that every kernel on the GPU will fill an recurrence and store on  positions that I will choose of a given array the corresponding values for F.   I  think that by expressing the tensors as hash tables, I am getting the representation of the data that is of minimum memory size   , is this assumption correct?

How can I fill the tensors to the local memory in order to achieve high performance and also  coalescence in the transfer of  data from global memory to the local memory of the device? the size of the buffer for the hash table for the final application will be between   1 and 80 approximately.

UPDATE: I experienced problems using aligned storage for the tensor because I  was unable to manage to find the right syntactic expression to have access to the key and value stored in the structure H_element. Therefore I am switching to the following simplified version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



struct point{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

  inline point operator=(double c) {
    x=c;
    y=c;
    z=c;
    return {x,y,z};
  }

  inline point operator=(point a) {
    x=a.x;
    y=a.y;
    z=a.z;
    return a;
  }

  inline point operator+(point a) {
    return {a.x+x,a.y+y,a.z+z};
  }

  inline point operator-(point a) {
    return {a.x-x,a.y-y,a.z-z};
  }

  inline point operator*(double k) {
    return {k*x,k*y,k*z};
  }



  inline bool operator==(point a) {
    if (a.x==x && a.y==y && a.z==z)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }


  double norm2()
  {
    return x*x + y*y + z*z;
  }

};

inline point operator*(double k, point p) {
  return {k*p.x,k*p.y,k*p.z};
}

inline point operator*(point p,double k) {
  return {k*p.x,k*p.y,k*p.z};
}



static inline bool is_in(int &na, int &nb, int N)
{
    if(N < 0 || N > (na + nb) || na < 0 || nb < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
/// elements of the hash table
template<typename T>
struct H_element{
  int key;
  T value;
};

template<typename T>
struct ascending
{
  inline bool operator() (const H_element<T>& struct1, const H_element<T>& struct2)
  {
    return (struct1.key < struct2.key);
  }
};


template <typename T, size_t dim_na=6,size_t dim_nb=6,size_t dim_N=12>
struct E_coeff_sparce {


  enum {LEN1 = dim_na };
  enum {LEN2 = dim_nb };
  enum {LEN3 = dim_N };


  enum {MAX_AM = dim_na-3 };



  ///container
  vector<H_element<T> > data;


  ///hash function
  static int Hash_func( int na, int nb,  int N) {
    return (nb*dim_na + na)*dim_nb + N;
  }

  ///Map from indices to keys
  T Binary_Search(int na, int nb, int N ) {
    int key=Hash_func(na,nb,N);

    int iteration = 0, left = 0, right = data.size()-1, mid;

    while (left <= right) {
      iteration++;
      mid = (int) ((left + right) / 2);
      if (data[mid].key == key) {
        iteration++;
    return  data[mid].value;
      }
      else if (key > data[mid].key )
    left = mid + 1;
      else
    right = mid - 1;
    }
    return T(0.0);

  }

  T operator()(int na,int nb, int N){
    return Binary_Search(na, nb, N );
  }


  ///generator of the hash table
  void Do_recurrence(point A, double alpha_a, int ax,  point B, double alpha_b, int bx,  bool Laplacian=true)
  {
    data.clear();

    point R = A - B;

    int na_max = ax + 1;
    int nb_max = bx + 1;

    if(Laplacian){
      na_max += 2;
      nb_max += 2;
    }
    int tmax  = na_max + nb_max - 1;

    T a = alpha_a;
    T b = alpha_b;
    T p = a + b;
    T factor = -(a * b / p);
    // if(is_in(0,0,0)){
      int key=Hash_func(0,0,0);
      H_element<T>  E= {key,std::exp(factor*R.x*R.x)};
      printf("%d     %e \n",key ,exp(factor*R.x*R.x));
      data.push_back(E);
      //}
    /// na_=0
    for(int nb_ = 1; nb_ < nb_max; nb_++){
      for(int t = 0; t < tmax; t++){

    int na_ = 0;
    int nb_p = nb_ - 1;
    int tp = t - 1;
    int tn = t + 1;

    double E_na__nb_p_tp = 0.0;
    if(is_in(na_, nb_p, tp)){
      E_na__nb_p_tp = Binary_Search(na_, nb_p, tp);
    }

    double E_na__nb_p_t = 0;
    if(is_in(na_, nb_p, t)) {
      E_na__nb_p_t = Binary_Search(na_, nb_p, t);
    }

    double E_na__nb_p_tn = 0;
    if(is_in(na_, nb_p, tn)) {
      E_na__nb_p_tn = Binary_Search(na_, nb_p, tn);
    }
    if(is_in(na_,nb_,t)){
      H_element<T>  E= {Hash_func(na_,nb_,t),1.0 / (2*p) * E_na__nb_p_tp + a / p* R.x * E_na__nb_p_t +  (t + 1)*E_na__nb_p_tn};
      if(E.value != 0.0){
        data.push_back(E);
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), ascending<T>());
        //printf("%d     %e \n",E.key ,E.value);
      }

    }
      }
    }
    //printf("******************\n");
    ///na_>0
    for(int nb_ = 0; nb_ < nb_max; nb_++) {
            for(int na_ = 1; na_ < na_max; na_++) {
                for(int t = 0; t < tmax; t++) {

                    int na_p = na_ - 1;
                    int tp = t - 1;
                    int tn = t + 1;

                    double E_na_p_nb__tp = 0;
                    if(is_in(na_p, nb_, tp)) {
                        E_na_p_nb__tp = Binary_Search(na_p, nb_, tp);
                    }

                    double E_na_p_nb__t = 0;
                    if(is_in(na_p, nb_, t)) {
                        E_na_p_nb__t = Binary_Search(na_p, nb_, t);
                    }

                    double E_na_p_nb__tn = 0;
                    if(is_in(na_p, nb_, tn)) {
                        E_na_p_nb__tn = Binary_Search(na_p, nb_, tn);
                    }

            if(is_in(na_,nb_,t)){
              H_element<T>  E= {Hash_func(na_,nb_,t), 1.0 / (2*p) * E_na_p_nb__tp - b / p* R.x * E_na_p_nb__t +  (t + 1)*E_na_p_nb__tn};
              if(E.value != 0.0){
            data.push_back(E);
            std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), ascending<T>());
            //printf("%d     %e \n",E.key ,E.value);
              }
            }
                }
            }
        }
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
      printf("%d     %e \n",data[i].key ,data[i].value);
    printf("stored: %d \n",data.size());
  }



  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm,E_coeff_sparce<T> ob){
  /** Formatted output of the tensor to  specified stream
  */
    printf("Unfolded Tensor.\n");
    printf("....................\n");
    cout<<"na "<<right;
    cout<<"nb "<<right;
    cout<<"N      "<<right;
    cout<<"value "<<endl;


    int data_PRECISION = 8;
    int data_WIDTH = 15;
    strm.setf(ios::showpoint);
    strm.precision(data_PRECISION);


    for(int i=0; i< dim_na; i++){
      for(int j=0; j< dim_nb; j++){
    for(int N=0; N< dim_N; N++){
      if(is_in(i,j,N)){
        strm<<i<<"  ";

        strm<<j<<"  ";

        strm<<N<<"  ";
        strm<< ob.Hash_func(i, j, N )<<"     ";
        strm<<right;
        strm.setf(ios::showpoint);
        strm.precision(data_PRECISION);
        strm.width(data_WIDTH);
        strm<<ob(i,j,N);
        strm<<endl;
      }
    }
      }
    }
    return strm;
  }

};


template<typename T>
void f(point A, T a, int na, point B, T b, int nb)
{
  E_coeff_sparce<double> E;
  E.Do_recurrence(A, a, na,  B, b, nb, true);

  T p = a+b;
  printf("       RESULTS          \n");
  printf("........................\n");
  printf("na  nb     F   \n");
  for(int i_na=0; i_na<=na; i_na++)
    for(int i_nb=0; i_nb<=nb; i_nb++)
      printf("%d   %d  %e \n",i_na, i_nb, pow(M_PI/p, 1.5)*E(i_na,i_nb,0) );

    //return pow(M_PI/p, 1.5)*E(na,nb,0);
    return;

}


int main() {


  point A = {0.,1.43233673, -0.96104039};
  point B = {0.0,0.0,0.24026010};

  double alpha_a = 3.425250914;
  double alpha_b = 5.033151319;


  E_coeff_sparce<double> E;
  E.Do_recurrence(A, alpha_a, 2,  B, alpha_b, 2, true);

  cout<<E<<endl;


  //cout<<"F = "<<<<endl;
  f(A, alpha_a, 2,  B, alpha_b, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hash table approach is actually very similar to the COO format for representing sparse matrix, as all the components are ordered.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#coordinate-format-coo

Compared to COO format, I would recommend you use CSR or CSC format to store the sparse tenser.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#compressed-sparse-row-format-csr

CSR and CSC format are commonly used in sparse matrix operations. When applying to tensor, you could store a tensor(`h`x`w`x`d`) as a matrix(`h*w`x`d`) or matrix(`h`x`d*w`). Then you could make use of the sparse BLAS routines provided by cuSPARSE library for further operations.

At this time it is actually hard to make the final decision on which format to use, as you did not provide any detail about your reduction-like operations. Your approach seems very good on memory size, but binary search has terrible performance on GPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I don't have planed to use routines of linear algebra with the tensor. In my application tensors play a role of recursion tables and again, my aim is to guarantee the best compromise between size in the memory and performance.

Comment: @RubénDaríoGuerrero maybe you could provide more detail about what operation you will do with the tensors, so that the performance with various storage schemes can be evaluated. Your approach seems very good on memory size, but binary search has terrible performance on GPU.

Comment: Thanks for help, I provided additional details of the computation I want to do.